# How to use non udf method in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've code whose which is like below

```
myDF.map{ x =>

  val inp = MyUtils.doSomething(x.value) //accepts Int values and return Int
  MyInfo(inp)

}
```

here `MyUtils.doSomething` is normal function `(non UDF)` in my spark scala code. Its working fine

But when I do like this

```
   val DF = myDF.withColumn("value", lit(MyUtils.doSomething(col("value").asInstanceOf[Int].toInt)))
```

why its showing error

```
class org.apache.spark.sql.Column cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer
```

How can I fix this ? Is there any way I could get underlying value of `col("value")`, so that I could use this in my `doSomething` function.

Not sure why `col("value").asInstanceOf[Int].toInt` its not giving Int value?

Answer (score 2):

> Not sure why col("value").asInstanceOf[Int].toInt its not giving Int value?

Well because how do you want to cast `Column("colName", 21, false)`? That `asInstanceOf` will basically make compiler ignore the fact that an object of type `Column` is an integer, and you'll face exceptions in runtime instead. You should program your code in a way that you won't even need `asInstanceOf`. About your first consideration, that `UDF` is basically a function, serialized by spark into spark slaves and executed on columns, so you'll have to do it like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val doSomethingUdf = udf(MyUtils.doSomething)
// if doSomething is defined as a method "def doSomething ..."
// then it would be better to do
// udf(MyUtils.doSomething _)
```

Comment: @Amim, so we pass col types to udf, so it converts col("value") to literal Int value (accepted by doSomething function) by spark framework itself ?

Comment: @OxanaGrey Not that it converts a column value to integer, it uses the underlying value of the column

Comment: correct...Is there any way we could get underlying value of col ? searched  but didnt find any way..!

Comment: @OxanaGrey there is no way as far as I know, what’s wrong with udfs?

Comment: I had 2 days figuring it out to get underlying value..wasted..! no issue in using UDFs..but curious to know..there must be some way using code we could unwrap column and get the value inside it.. :)